# iOS 9 AVPlayer rotation trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I have some strange thing - after rotating of `AVPlayer`, I'm updating textField and slider of progress by timer, but view with controllers change coordinates after `AVPlayer`

```
mPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
mPlayer = [mPlayer initWithURL:streamURL];
playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:mPlayer];
[[[self view] layer] insertSublayer:playerLayer atIndex:0];
[playerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

rotating

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.ButtonsView.frame.size.height);
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {

        self.ButtonsView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - self.ButtonsView.frame.size.width) /2, playerLayer.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.ButtonsView.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

and after change of timer, coordinates of ButtonView became wrong

```
- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
    self.tfCurrent.text = [self textFormatting : self.videoCurrentTime];
}
```

first second coords are good. Why my View redraw? thanks!